# Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my controller i was trying to update my product, product name here is unique and here i wanted to update only price. so name will be as it but as i defined name as a unique field though i haven't changed the name it throws me unique name validation error as this name already exist. How do i ignore that validation request when i don't update the unique value?

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
           $this->validate($request, [              
            'name'=> 'required|unique:products,'.$id,
            ]);        
            $product= Product::find($id);
            $product->name = Input::get('name');
            $product->price = Input::get('price'); 
            $product->save();
       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to:

```
'name'=> 'required|unique:products,name' . $id,
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `unique column name` to validation rule:

```
'name'=> 'required|unique:products,name,'.$id,
```

Answer (score 2):

### Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique):

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

> The field under validation must be unique on a given database table.
>   If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.

**Try this:**

```
        'name'=> 'required|unique:products,name'.$id,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add following

```
'name' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
```

I lots tried but didn't working and then i realized that name field also covered in different array inside `$request->validate` array.

**Note :** `ignore()` function expect id and `unique()` function expect Tablename